# How to update android studio emulator to a specific version?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

How to update android studio emulator to a specific version? I want to update top 30.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these steps

1. Open the Preferences window by clicking File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences).

2.In the left panel, click Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates.

3.Be sure that Automatically check for updates is checked, then select a channel from the drop-down list

image link = https://developer.android.com/studio/images/preferences-updates_2x.png

3.Click Apply or OK.

Have A Nice Day!